# Realm Platform: How do I force sync before app goes into background?

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I need to keep track of devices that are actively running the app. Right now I have a status field that changes to 1 when the app is first launched or when the device becomes active. When the user presses the home button, I set the status field to 0 upon receiving the notification `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`

```
    if(self.device) {
        [self.realm transactionWithBlock:^{
            self.device.status = 0;
        }];
    }
    self.device = nil;
    [self.realm refresh];
```

However, I check the data in Realm Cloud, and it doesn't seem to be updating at all. Is there some way to force update the sync of my Realm data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve this by only using `realm platform`, I think you should implement a data updating logic, for example, every 5-second client should update a value, it can be the current timestamp and you can recognize online users by the last timestamp value.

in my opinion, a simple [socket.io](http://socket.io) implementation can be a better solution, you can save users connection status by saving them in the socket server. you just need to save timestamp when the client has connected to the server and when he has disconnected.

I believe you can do same with `ROS` but I'm not sure they provide public API for user connection event or status ...